# SignalR and AngularJS directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, signalr.client

every one. I figure out what is the reson of my recent problem, but now I need an advice how to fix that. The error occurs while I'm trying to start SignalR javascript client (with using https://github.com/JustMaier/angular-signalr-hub) for ng-init directive.
Here is the error:

```
Error: SignalR: Connection must be started before data can be sent. Call .start() before .send()
at Object.signalR.fn.signalR.send (localhost:4745.lan/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.1.
```

When I use SignalR script for ng-click everithing is ok. Here is just a test app:

```
angular.module('app', ['SignalR'])
.factory('SomeService', ['$rootScope', 'Hub', function ($rootScope, Hub) {

//declaring the hub connection
var hub = new Hub('myHub', {

    //client side methods
    listeners: {
        'doAction': function (message) {
            alert(message);
            console.log("It works");
            $rootScope.$apply();
        }
    },
    //server side methods
    methods: ['someAction'],


    //handle connection error
    errorHandler: function (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }

});
var load = function () {
    console.log(hub);

    hub.someAction(); //Calling a server method
};

return {
     loadSomeMethod: load
};
}])
   .controller('appController', ['$scope', 'SomeService', function ($scope, SomeService) {
    $scope.callMethod = SomeService.loadSomeMethod;
    $scope.text = "Index from Angular";
  }]);
```

View page

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="appController">
<h2>{{text}}</h2>
<input type="button" name="GreetAll" value="Greet All" ng-click="callMethod()" />
</div>
@section scripts
{
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery.signalR")
@*<script src="~/SignalR/Hubs"></script>*@
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular-resource")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular-signalr-hub")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/App")
@*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/AppNew")*@
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling the load method before the server is fully started. the SignalR hub is started asynchronously, this means you have to ensure it has started before calling methods on it.

I had a look at the signalr hub class you're using. It puts the promise from the start method on the returned object. You can access it via hub.promise. Register a callback to e notified when the connection started successfully:

```
hub.promise.done(function(){
    // connection established
    // call your hub method here
});
```

You can't call the hub methods synchronously from your controller, instead you need to provide a promise to the controller. The controller can then register a callback to that promise and call the hub methods. Of course there are numerous other possible solutions (like using angularjs eventing) but in the end it boils down to this: you can't call methods on the hub directly at initialization time in the controller.